# Symfony 2 Controller dependencies, extending ContainerAware

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-components

## Edit

after digging into the symfony code, particularly the ControllerResolver, it seems what im trying to do actually isnt possible unless i subclass/implement ControllerResolverInterface myself.

this is the following code which instantiates the controller passed from the route:

```
protected function createController($controller)
{
    if (false === strpos($controller, '::')) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find controller "%s".', $controller));
    }

    list($class, $method) = explode('::', $controller, 2);

    if (!class_exists($class)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist.', $class));
    }

    return array(new $class(), $method);
}
```

as you can see on the last line, this is always instantiated with no arguments passed, so i will have to override this method to inject something in that way. feels very hacky.

---

## Original Question

I'm trying to figure out how I can inject services into a custom controller defined in dynamic routes using Symfony components (e.g. *not* the full stack framework).

Please note, I am *not* using the full stack framework and am not using their DemoBundle src code. I have a `composer.json` file that requires components, so I have a custom `index.php` file which is more or less the same as that detailed here:

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/55/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-12

I have the following:

```php
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routes->add(
    'some route name',
    new Route(
      'a route path', 
      array(
        '_controller' => 'App\MyBundle\Controller\MyController::handle'
      )
    )
);
```

Then I have the following within `App/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MyExtension.php`:

```php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $loader = new XmlFileLoader(
      $container, 
      new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resource/config')
    );
    $loader->load('services.xml');
}
```

`App/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.xml`:

```xml
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services 
                      http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<services>
  <service id="templating" class="Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface" />
  <service id="navigation" class="App\MyBundle\Controller\MyController">
    <argument type="service" id="templating" />
  </service> 
</services>
</container>
```

I'm basically trying to get the templating service injected into the `MyController` constructor, and my understanding is the `MyExtension` file should be loaded automatically. I assume as I'm not using the full stack framework, this is the reason why, but how can I get this working?

Comment: Loading the extensions is part of the framework.  It occurs when you add a bundle to you AppKernel.  So no, it probably won't be automatic.  I have not read through the entire tutorial but I suspect you might need to modify src/app.php?  Look for wherever the container is being built.

Comment: Hi, there is no app.php - as stated, i am using standalone components, NOT the full framework itself. i am using my own container. the issue is how i can inject something into the controller that the Route _controller attribute defines.

Comment: I understand that.  The link you provided actually points to part 6 of the tutorial instead of part 12.  Might want to fix that.  I was referring to the src/app.php from part 6.

Comment: So looking at part 12, you will need to modify container.php to instantiate your extension class and call the load method.  You might run into some other issues.  Might be best to just add your services directly to container.php just to get started.

Comment: And I don't see the templating component in the composer.json file.  You may run into some problems there.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with overriding ControllerResolver. The full stack framework does that too. Otherwise the Controllers couldn't be ContainerAware.

I also use Symfony Components without the full stack framework and, partly copying the full stack framework, I ended up with this in order to inject the container in my controllers

```
class ControllerResolver extends SymfonyControllerResolver
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;

        parent::__construct($logger);
    }

    protected function createController($controller)
    {
        if (false === strpos($controller, '::')) {
           throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find controller "%s".', $controller));
        }

        list($class, $method) = explode('::', $controller, 2);

        $class = "Namespace\\Controllers\\" . $class;

        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist.', $class));
        }

        $controller = new $class();
        if ($controller instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
            $controller->setContainer($this->container);
        }

        return array($controller, $method);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to add possibility to define controllers as services you can replace

```
if (!class_exists($class)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist.', $class));
    }

    $controller = new $class();
    if ($controller instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
        $controller->setContainer($this->container);
    }
```

With something like

```
if (!class_exists($class)) {
    if (!$this->container->has($class)) {
        throw new \Exception( ... );
    }
    $controller = $this->container->get($class);

    return array($controller, $method);
}

$controller = new $class();
if ($controller instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
    $controller->setContainer($this->container);
}

return array($controller, $method);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first. You don't have to inject services into your controller. A normal controller will extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` which gets the hole container injected. This means you can access the `templating` service like this:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $templating = $this->get('templating');
}
```

But Symfony2 gives you also the possibility of creating controller as services. That means you remove the extend from the default `Controller` and instead of that only inject the services you need (usually `request` and `response`). More information can be found in [this great post](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/04/15/symfony2-controller-as-service/) by Richard Miller.
You can also read [this post](http://pooteeweet.org/blog/1947) by Lukas Kahwe Smith, in which he talks about why he thinks services are a 'best practise' (please note that Fabien, former of the Symfony project, disagrees with this).

Comment: The first comment isnt relevant as, as stated in the question, i am not using any of Symfonys 'Bundles' so cannot extend them. the latter is what i am trying to do, but isnt quite working. i suspect this is down to not loading the config files correctly..