# Standalone Symfony DIC in my controllers

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-components

I'm using Symfony DIC, Routing and ControllerResolver in my project following [Create your own PHP Framework](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html)

I do not understand how I can correctly transfer services to the constructor of my controller without using the Config Component or set container in the controller?
Routing:

```
$routes->add('mycontroller', new Routing\Route('/', ['_controller' => 'controller.mycontroller::indexAction']));
```

Controller:

```
    class MyController implements ContainerAwareInterface
    {
        use ContainerAwareTrait;

        protected $entityManager;

        public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $doctrine->entityManager;
        }

        public function indexAction()
        {
            ...
        }
   }
```

Container and handle:

```
$container = new DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder();
$container->register('context', Routing\RequestContext::class);
$container->register('matcher', Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher::class)
             ->setArguments([$routes, new Reference('context')]);
$container->register('doctrine', Doctrine::class)
             ->setArguments($db);
...
$container->register('controller.mycontroller',MyController::class)
             ->setArguments([new Reference('doctrine')]);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel $kernel
 */
$kernel = $container->get('base');
/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response
 */
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$response->send();
```

Comment: Typically you would define the controller as a service which would take care of injecting whatever you need.  At some point during routing you would pull the controller out of the container.

Comment: @Cerad

I do not understand how Router should understand that it should use a container. If I now define the Controller as a Service and pass the service name to the Router, it does not find the class and returns an error.
I'm looking at ControllerResolver code and it seems to me that it does not access the services.

Comment: That is the framework's job i.e. your code.  The controller resolver itself knows nothing about the container.  All I can suggest is to install the actual Symfony framework and take a look at how it does it.

Comment: I see you added some code.  You are still not quite understanding the difference between the "make your own framework" article and the actual Symfony framework.  You are trying to inject the doctrine service without actually defining it.  That is all part of the actual full blown Symfony framework.  Either use the actual framework or buckle down and learn how to configure your own doctrine services.

Comment: @Cerad
I certainly defined  the doctrine service, just removed this part of the code for brevity on SO.

Comment: Okay.  So if you are injecting the doctrine service then why are you making the controller container aware?  The controller already has the service(s) it needs.  And where are you processing the matched route?

Comment: @Cerad
Updated.
If I use this example, the container is not found.
If I pass the container to the router using namespace, then the container in the controller is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152915/discussion-between-houseintheforest-and-cerad).

Comment: In the Symfony framework, the controller resolver tests the controller and, if it implements the container aware interface, calls setContainer.  But that is framework code.  The out of the box component kernel code knows nothing about the container.

Comment: @Cerad
Thanks for the help.
Without overriding it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956418/8328328.

So without overriding Controller Resolver can not do.